# Why is this script getting back encoding-garbled gibberish?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, reddit

There's no way to paste it in from my console, but try running the script with "node file.js ttuuu ttppp", and you'll see what I mean. It's just choking on this invalid JSON response and crashing the script when it receives that...

Link: https://gist.github.com/bmproc/bdcd926c875597e3246b

Any ideas?

Comment: Not willing to run big script without knowing what its doing, and that's too big to full read quickly. First guess, you have `Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate` and no code to decompress the body?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Bingo! You're smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script specifies `'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',` so the response body is probably going to be Gzip or Deflate encoded as long as the server supports it.

Two options:

1. You'll need to either disable that and just get the response without compression.
2. Decompress the data by checking the `Content-Encoding` response header and then using `zlib.gunzip` or `zlib.inflate`. Your current code doesn't use streaming, but if it did, you would use `zlib.createGunzip()` or `zlib.createInflate()`